# Remove words that don't begin with upper case letters

Tags: sql, regex, impala

I have some sentences where I need to remove all words that don't begin with upper case letters. I'm trying to use regex in SQL with "regexp_replace".
Examples:

- "RB StabSS with delay 0-180 days" >> "RB StabSS"
- "IK ObeSS with delay 0-30 days"   >> "IK ObeSS"
- "StabSS without delay"            >> "StabSS"
- "IK without delay"                >> "IK"
- "ıK without DelAy"                >> DelAy
- "ık without DELay                 >> DELay
- "stabSS Without delay             >> Without

To clarify, what I need is to remove words if it doesn't begin with upper case letters. If word begins with upper case letter - I need to stay it entirely.
If word has upper letter in the middle of a word, but not in the first position - I need to remove this word.

How can I do it right?

Comment: It looks like you want to remove `0-180` and `0-30` as well?

Comment: nope.
i need to remove words which starts with a small letter including numbers and special characters. If words contain big letters I don't need to remove it

Comment: Hi Yurka, welcome to stack overflow! I happen to be a regex ninja, but your question is a bit vague. Need to know more examples, can you add examples of phrases you don't want regex to match? For example "rb Sta bla"? "Pa soBB bla"?

Comment: @Yurka please edit your question with some more guidelines as to what should be replaced or not (e.g. with Neithan's test values), then it can be re-opened and answered.

Answer (score 0):

Good day. Can you try this function?

' \b([A-Z])([a-zA-Z]+) '

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bafXWn/1)